# Calculate sum of vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to do this :

```
for(i in 1:5){ 
  O[i]=sum(y[i:i+m-1])}
```

`m` is an integer in [2,12]. But, in the output, I got for each `O[i]` the value of `y[i+1]` not the sum of `y[i]` and `y[i+1]`. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Try `i:(i+m-1)` instead of `i:i+m-1`.

Comment: ... and of course this is the most inefficient way to calculate a rolling sum in R.

Comment: you can also do: rollsum(x=y, k=m), where rollsum() is found in the 'zoo' library.

Comment: @Roland I bet I could write something far less efficient. It might be the least efficient of the ways sane people might do it, though.

Comment: @Glen_b  yeah!  Start a "anti-code-golf" contest!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter`.

```
filter(y, rep(1, m))
```